# Any examples on using Accel+Magnetic+Gyroscope to detect orientation?

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix

From what I understand the 3 fields are in rad/sec. Which are great for tracking 3D motion, but not great for using on their own (without calibaration).

So the idea seems to be to generate a matrix using the Accel+Magnetic, but since that isn't accurate, you use the gyroscope data to apply some correction to the data.

Has anyone got a class that manages this, or more information on how to do the actual correction to the Accel+Mag Matrix with the Orientation data?

Am I misunderstanding patterns here and can I use the Orientation sensor by itself, can it truly measure exact orientation or does it require the magnetic/accel to calibrate the system.

The matrices are destined to be used in a opengl camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had put up some code on GitHub a while back which I use in my app. It uses a Kalman filter to fix jittery values. https://github.com/a85/MagCompass/blob/master/src/com/rickreation/magcompass/HomeActivity.java

You can also use the ROTATION_VECTOR sensor type to get exact orientation if it's available. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR

Comment: I see you using that km0 variable, but it doesn't appear to affect the kFilteringFactor. It looks like it's just doing a 10% filtered blend between the two. I already do something very similar to reduce jitter.

I didn't look at the Kalman Filter, but it doesn't look like it's actually hooked up in that file right now. (it only operates on val[0] at the end of step, and val[0] is set at the beginning and not accessed elsewhere.

You don't seem to use either the gyro or that rotation_vector, however I'm looking into the rotation vector now. Perhaps my nexus s/xoom support it.

Comment: Missed the comment somehow. I'll have to check the code again. I had been trying different stuff but all the things required for working with the Kalman and the Exponential filter are there. I will post a more detailed answer here soon.